# An error due to which the app has a problem. ( wakelock_plus )

Tags: flutter, dart

Recently, when I wanted to exit my application in the emulator, I noticed an error in the debugger that caused the app to not be installed.

I will leave you the text of that error.

- [[debug console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxLqv.png)]
- [[debug console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7riYd.png)]

In the error, it is said that this error is related to the `wakelock_plus` library
Is. But **I have not installed** such a library. And according to the picture, I went to the requested location and defaultConfig `{ minSdkVersion 19 }`
I added it to Android, but the problem was still not solved and the app was not running.

Comment: editing the minSdkVersion should have helped. Maybe you did it at the wrong place. Are you sure you took the one in android/app/build.gradle? There should already be `minSdkVersion 16` most likely and this you need to change to 19

Comment: And about you not having added the library yourself, it could be that you use other libraries that use that, for example chewie, pod_player or fl_video

Comment: @Ivo Yes, I went to the mentioned route. But even `minSdkVersion`
It was not there and I created it manually and changed it to version 19.

Comment: maybe double check it and do a project wide search on "minSdkVersion" or "minSdkVersion 16" because I believe it must have been there already

Comment: minSdkVersion should be there in android\app\build.gradle file. or it would not build/run the app in the first place. you probably added minSdkVersion in android\build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem was solved.**
The main root of the problem is a library called `widget_from_html`
When it was added to the project, it installed other libraries, and one of those libraries caused the app to not run.
By removing widget_from_html
Its extra libraries were also removed and the problem was fixed.